# Change color profile in Photoshop without loosing layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-profile

**Is there a way to change the color profile e.g. from RGB to CMYK without merging all layers to one background layer?**

At this time I've two layers one pixel filled background and a curves layer. I want to leave the curves as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that adjustment layer has to go*. Once you have removed the adjustment layer then you can just choose the *Don't Flatten option*. Photoshop will complain, and righlty so, but will do what you ask.

Theres no way to convert a 3 channel curves layer to a 4 channel curves layer. Because they adjust differnet things. See CMYK is the inevrse of RGB so even the curves layer is now totally different.

* Now you can be smart about this and merge down the adjustment before conversion.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Didn't even thought about the difference of the curves.

But where can I finde the _Don't Flatten option_?

Comment: @Malte it appears in the conversion dialog when you do not have ANY adjustment layers